# Strange JPG color loss in Firefox (?)

Tags: firefox, jpeg

Really strange problem:

http://tracker.fusiondev.com.ar/themes/bavarian_dawn/images/original.jpg

http://tracker.fusiondev.com.ar/themes/bavarian_dawn/images/bg-orange.jpg

There is a HUGE change opening both in Firefox, but none on Chrome.... what could it be? I am trying to slow down the size of original.jpg, opened it with Photoshop and exported JPG with 80% quality.

Any one seen this or have information?

Comment: Must be your copy of Firefox that's somehow borked or old, they look identical here in FF26 under Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to Embed Color Profile, I marked this Option in Photoshop and Firefox displayed the correct color.